# only a portion of data comes out of the https.request

Tags: javascript, api, http, request, httprequest

I'm new to JavaScript and stack overflow so please be patient with me.

I'm trying to communicate with an api and the data I get back is getting corrupted (?) when I'm trying to extract it from the function.

When I try to show it in console inside the main function is the only time I get the full data, if I try to extract it (like the code below) or if I try to write it to a txt file even inside the main function (where the console was showing the full data) a very small part of the actual data comes out.

```
const myTargetList = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const req = https.request(requestOptions, (response) => {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      response.on("data", (responseBodyBytes) => {
        //console.log  (hex2ascii(byteToHexString(responseBodyBytes)))
        resolve(hex2ascii(byteToHexString(responseBodyBytes)));
      });
    } else {
      reject(response.statusCode);
    }
  });
  req.on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
  req.end();
});

myTargetList
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: In a stream, the `data` event will be triggered multiple times with chunks of the stream. When it's completely done, the `end` event will be triggered.